# How to create subdomain & add city name in joomla virtuemart?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla 2.5 & Virtuemart.

I have website like yellow pages. I have to show records city wise.

I have enabled SEO & enabled .htaccess.

Currently my url is

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/yellowpages
```

Now i want if i'm accessing from toronto then it should be

```
http://yellowpages.mywebsite.com/toronto
```

how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain part of this has to be configured in your hosting panel when you put the website on a live server. Joomla doesn't care where it is installed whether it's a sub domain, root domain, or subfolder. Just set up your hosting to have the subdomain you want then install your joomla there.

As for adding the city name you will need to do the following -

1. Create a Virtuemart category for each city
2. Create a top level menu item for each city you are using

If you need to make the links to the cities submenus, then you will want to create the menus in a hidden menu, then use menu aliases where ever you want the links to show. This will insure that the URL is subdomain.domain.com/menu-item-alias